# On click, display a div, wait a second, load some ajax, wait a second, and hide it all?

Tags: jquery

I have a function which when clicked shows a div, then waits a second, calls some ajax, shows the result, then waits a second, then hides again...

It all seems to be working, except for the hide part at the end.

My code looks like this:

```
  $('#wrap').slideDown('fast').delay(1000,function(){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/stuff.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

      $('#wrap').show().delay(1000,function(){

        $('#wrap').fadeOut('slow'); 

      });

    }
  });
```

});

What am I missing here? It seems pretty straightforward that in the line:

```
$('#wrap').show().delay(1000,function() { ///// }
```

The callback function to hide the #wrap should run. Why doesn't it?

In addition to this, I'm looking for a bit of a mechanical style animation where by the slideDown occurs, then a second later, the ajax is executed... then the fadeout... but it all seems to happen all at once even though I have those delay() functions in there. I've tried to mess around with the queue() function but it seems to evade my inferior brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"The callback function to hide the #wrap should run. Why doesn't it?"*

Because the [`delay()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method doesn't accept a callback.

```
$('#wrap').slideDown('fast')
          .delay(1000)
          .queue( function ( nxt ) {
              $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '/stuff.php',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $('#wrap').show().delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
                 }
              });
              nxt();
          });
```

This uses the [`queue()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method so that you can chain the AJAX requrest

Comment: Interesting! I've learnt alot from your response. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I hope this may be helpful

```
$('#yourClickableElement').click(function() {
  $('#wrap').slideDown(1000, function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/stuff.php',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#wrap").show(1000).fadeOut("slow");
      }
    });    
  });
});
```